# Проблема с подтверждением личности в аккаунте Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

у меня проблемы с регистрацией на Гугл Плей Консоль.

Я оплатил 25 баксов, но проблема в том, что при подтверждении личности он говорит, что у меня "Украина", но на самом деле я из России.

И что мне теперь делать? Я сменил платёжный профиль, но всё равно показывается, что я могу подтвердить личность только как Украинец.

Писать в поддержку и возвращать средства, регистрировать новый аккаунт?
Очень жаль, если так, ибо адрес очень подходящий.

Почему всё так сложно?

Comment: Если вопрос "почему так сложно", то  это не сюда.

Comment: У меня все планы насмарку из-за этой фигни